# Как задать имя выходного бинарника на этапе генерации проекта для VisualStudio

Tags: компиляция, cmake

Хочу собрать zlib 1.2.11 из сорцов, под Windows, при помощи CMake 3.8 и Visual Studio 2008.

Генерирую файл проекта для студии:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\build
```

Затем компилирую и устанавливаю zlib:

```
msbuild.exe zlib.sln /verbosity:detailed /p:Configuration="Release"
msbuild.exe install.vcproj /verbosity:detailed /p:Configuration="Release"
```

Весь процесс завершается успешно. НО скомпилированная библиотека называется `zlib.dll`, а мне нужно, чтобы она называлась `zlib1.dll`.

Вопрос: возможно ли как-то указать/сконфигурировать CMake, чтобы он при создании файла проекта в `OutputFile` вписывал нужное мне имя бинарника, а не какое ему вздумается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без изменения `CMakeLists.txt` - никак. Проще всего найти `add_library(zlib ...)` и заменить на `add_library(zlib1 ...)`.

Comment: Я очень надеялся, что есть какой-то стандартный способ и это можно сделать как-то извне, не редактирую сорцы. Для `zlib` я решение нашёл, но, к примеру, есть ещё proj4, которая генерирует вообще зубодробительное имя `proj_4_9.dll`, хотя мне надо просто `proj.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Углубленное чтение сорцов CMakeLists.txt навело на флаг `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`

```
if(UNIX)
    # On unix-like platforms the library is almost always called libz
   set_target_properties(zlib zlibstatic PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME z)
   if(NOT APPLE)
     set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--version-script,\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib.map\"")
   endif()
elseif(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS AND WIN32)
    # Creates zlib1.dll when building shared library version
    set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES SUFFIX "1.dll")
endif()
```

Если его установить, то выходное имя получается таким, как мне надо.

Т.е. правильная команда имеет вид:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\build
```

Comment: А, я воспринял вашу `1` в вопросе не буквально, а как "что угодно". Да, в случае zlib это правильное решение, разработчики сами позаботились об этом.

Comment: @arrowd Вопрос был общий, но на частном примере. И как на зло, оказалось, что этот частный пример имел довольно лёгкое решение.